# CRAN R package examples and vignette when output is pdf

Tags: r, pdf, devtools, cran

I have an R package that I will be submitting to CRAN.  The only output from my package is a pdf file (V1.0).  Are there any tips on how to code the examples and vignettes for a package like this?  Any devtools that would help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Writing R Extensions, Section 1.4 "Writing Package Vignettes"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Writing-package-vignettes)

Comment: Or if you want something pre-made and working, install the [rmarkdown](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rmarkdown) package and select File->New File->R Markdown and select 'From Template' which will show you a package vignette template.

Comment: By "only output from my package is a PDF file" do you mean that the function(s) you have in the pkg only create PDF output? If that's the case you can do what Dirk suggested, but also use the `magick` package to turn PDF pages into images that can be embedded into the vignette(s). The examples can just generate PDFs (make sure to put them in a temp dir as CRAN executes the examples). You can also write tests that compare test PDF output with known gd PDF output.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a special temp dir at CRAN?  Or a special way to indicate the directory is temporary?  And any advice on comparing two output PDF?  So far the best thing I've found is [diff-pdf](http://vslavik.github.io/diff-pdf/)